# Combining Binary Search Trees

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

the problem I am having trouble with is as follows.

> Suppose that you have two different binary search trees, A and B, and
>   you somehow know that the largest element in A is less than the
>   smallest element in B. Suppose also that height(A) < height(B). Give
>   an algorithm for destructively creating a binary search tree that will
>   contain all the elements in A ∪ B and that runs in time O(height(A)).

So since the largest element in A is less than the smallest in B, that means every element in A is smaller than every element in B. In the new tree, the left hand side should be tree A and the right hand side should be tree B. But how do you do the merge programatically in time O(height(A))? Won't you need to loop through B as well? (which would make it O(height(A)+height(B))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the new tree, the left hand side should be tree A and the right hand side should be tree B.

Then what would the element at the root node be?

> But how do you do the merge programatically in time O(height(A))?

If you were right, then you could do it in O(1): `node(X, A, B)` (pseudocode for creating a node with element X, left subtree A, and right subtree B).

> Won't you need to loop through B as well? (which would make it O(height(A)+height(B))

If by "loop through B" you mean visiting all elements, then that would take even longer. In a balanced search tree, `height(B)` is proportional to `log(size(B))`.

---

What you can do instead is walk down the rightmost branch of A (this takes `O(height(A))` steps). Once you've found the end, insert B there (by assigning to `node.right`, in `O(1)`).

Comment: I see now. Thanks. Still wondering though, after finding the rightmost branch of A, how can you insert the tree B there? By inserting the tree, do you mean inserting each element of B into A? Or putting B in as a subtree? What would the code look like?

Comment: @KevinKevinz Depends on the programming language. In C, it would probably look like `void combine(Node **pp, Node *b) { while (*pp) { pp = &(*pp)->right; } *pp = b; } ... combine(&A, B);`

Answer (score 6):

As the problem is stated currently, you could just append the root of B tree as a right child of the largest element (which is the rightmost leaf) of A tree.

The complexity would be O(height(A)) - to find the leaf.